# Trouble calling a method in an init

Tags: swift

I have this:

```
class SomeClass {

    let title: String
    let content: String
    let date: String?

    init(title: String, content: String) {        
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = getDateString()        
    }

    func getDateString() -> String {        
        return "A date"      
    }    
}
```

However I'm getting a compiler error "Use of "self" method call in getDateString() before all stored properties are initialized". Just want to set something in my init() by using a method. How do I get around this? Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possibly because of a missing `super.init()` in the beginning of the init function

Comment: It doesn't need this. This is the base class

Comment: Indeed. My bad. Are they constant for a reason? Any reason not to use `var` for `date` instead?

Comment: It's constant because it's for the date the object is created and hence will not change later. Changing it to a var also doesn't make a difference and I still get the same compiler error.

Comment: I believe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646838/calling-instance-method-during-initialization-in-swift

Comment: @KexAri in that case, the simplest way to do it is 'class C {
    let created = NSDate()
}'

Comment: @KexAri The comment by user3441734 is the best solution. Also because you should use the 'NSDate' type, not 'String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You cannot use self before all the stored properties have been initialised

The rule is simple and you are violating it here

```
self.date = getDateString()
```

infact this line is equivalente to

```
self.date = self.getDateString()
```

and as you can see you are using `self` while `date` has not been initialised yet.

You must init `date` before calling the instance method `getDateString()`.

### A class method

If you really want to call a method to initialize `date` it must be a `class method`

```
class SomeClass {

    let title: String
    let content: String
    let date: String?

    init(title: String, content: String) {

        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = SomeClass.getDateString()

    }

    class func getDateString() -> String {
        return "A date"
    }
}
```

### A few improvements

1. If then `date` should contain... a Data then its type should be NSDate, not `String`
2. If the `date` property should indicate the time when the value has been created then you can assign it `= NSDate()` on the declaration of the property
3. `created` is a better name for this property

*These 3 suggestions comes from the comment of user `user3441734`.*

This is the updated code

```
class SomeClass {
    let title: String
    let content: String
    let created = NSDate()

    init(title: String, content: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
    }
}
```