# 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized in struct

Tags: swift, struct, initialization

I want `CurrendData.location` to get its random value once `CurrentData` gets initialized. I came up following code:

```
struct CurrentData {
    var size: (x: Int, y: Int)
    var location: (x: Int, y: Int)
        
    init(size: (x: Int, y: Int)) {
        self.size = size
        self.location = (getRandom(size.x), getRandom(size.y)) //error
    }
    
    private func getRandom (_ value:Int) -> Int {
        return Int.random(in: 0...value-1)
    }
}
```

But I get this error: "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized". How can it be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble calling a method in an init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380726/trouble-calling-a-method-in-an-init). Note that for a struct a `static func` is the same as `class func` for a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead defining your getRandom as an instance method, define it as a static one, then reference it by a type name (`CurrentData`) or `Self`

```
struct CurrentData {
    var size: (x: Int, y: Int)
    var location: (x: Int, y: Int)
        
    init(size: (x: Int, y: Int)) {
        self.size = size
        location = (Self.getRandom(size.x), Self.getRandom(size.y))
    }
    
    private static func getRandom (_ value:Int) -> Int {
        Int.random(in: 0...value-1)
    }
}
```

Other solution is to define your `location`property as a lazy one, then the `self` is accessible and the location will be executed only once and after being called in the code.

```
struct CurrentData {
    var size: (x: Int, y: Int)
    lazy var location: (x: Int, y: Int) = {
        (getRandom(size.x), getRandom(size.y))
    }()
        
    init(size: (x: Int, y: Int)) {
        self.size = size
    }
    
    private func getRandom (_ value:Int) -> Int {
        Int.random(in: 0...value-1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`getRandom` is an instance method, so it is called on `self` (however, Swift lets you omit `self` when accessing instance methods/properties).

If you want to be able to call a function from `init`, you need to declare it as a `static` method rather than an instance method. You can then call the static method by writing out the type name (`CurrentData`) or simply using `Self`.

```
struct CurrentData {
    var size: (x: Int, y: Int)
    var location: (x: Int, y: Int)
        
    init(size: (x: Int, y: Int)) {
        self.size = size
        self.location = (Self.getRandom(size.x), Self.getRandom(size.y))
    }
    
    private static func getRandom (_ value:Int) -> Int {
        Int.random(in: 0...value-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Static solution is fit. Good catch!