# `self` used before all stored properties are initialized and I have no idea why

Tags: swift

No idea why this error occurred, and I suspect that it's just me putting initialization in the wrong place. I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474545/self-used-before-all-stored-properties-are-initialized) but didn't help. I can't figure out why.

```
struct TodosDocument: FileDocument {
    ...
    var defaultText: String = defaultContent
    var content: String
    ...
    init(content: String = defaultContent, defaultText: String = defaultContent) {
        self.defaultText = defaultText
        self.content = content
        do {
            self.todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Context.self, from: content.data(using: .utf8)!)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR \(error)")
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.TodoType] }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        self.content = string
        do {
            self.todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Context.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            self.todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Context.self, from: defaultText.data(using: .utf8)!) // <- here
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You just cant user `defaultText` for assignment inside init. Bcz The compiler in Swift works like you should not use self objects/properties in right side of assignment operand inside init.

Comment: Move the decoding stuff out of the init methods, they are causing the errors and also that kind of code doesn't really belong in an init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a gander here in assuming that XCode is complaining over the fact that `self.todo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Context.self, from: defaultText.data(using: .utf8)!)` is not a static var.

So maybe check out this post for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64207731/9714666 (this one explains it best rather than your linked one :))